# Accessing environment secrets from cron-initiated shell script

Tags: linux, cron, environment-variables, fly

I have an app that uses cron to kick off shell scripts that initiate a python script. I also use fly.io's secrets manager. The python script accesses the secrets in the environment. This all works fine if I call the python script directly, or kick off the shell script directly, but when cron kicks off the shell scripts, the environment variables are not available.

> Note: The Fly.io agent on the host uses this token to decrypt your app
> secrets and inject them into your VM as environment variables at boot
> time.

Any ideas how to get this to work? Here are the relevant code snippets:

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.10
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron
RUN apt-get -y install vim

# set up log files
RUN mkdir /app/log
RUN touch /app/log/log.log
RUN chmod -R +rw /app/log

# make scripts executable
RUN chmod +x /app/python_script.py
RUN chmod -R +x /app/bin

# set up cron
RUN echo "* * * * * root /app/bin/my-script.sh" >> /etc/cron.d/crontab

# must end with new line
RUN echo "" >> /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/crontab

CMD /app/bin/start-cron.sh
```

`start-cron.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# start cron - -f to run in foreground
/usr/sbin/cron -f
```

`my-script.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/python /app/python_script.py close >> /app/log/log.log 2>&1
```

`python_script.py`

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # example, the script is big
    if not os.getenv("SOME_SECRET"):
        raise Exception
```

The python script is just an example, but if I run the script myself with `python python_script.py`, it does not raise. If I run the shell script with `bin/my-script.sh`, it does not raise. However, the logs show that it raises every minute with cron kicking it off.

Any ideas how to make the environment secrets available in this scenario?

Comment: You're presumably setting the environment variables in your `.profile` script. This isn't run from cron. You need to set them explicitly in the script that runs from cron.

Comment: @Barmar any ideas on how to do that without hardcoding secrets?

Comment: Put them in a script that you source from both `.profile` and in the `cron` command.

Comment: E.g. if you put them in `.envvars`, put `source .envvars` at the beginning of `my-script.sh`

Comment: @Barmar Got it. So they would have to be in a file somewhere, I can't access them out of the current env vars on the system.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "current env vars on the system". Most environment variables are not system-wide, they're per-user and established in your shell startup file.

Comment: @Barmar I'm using fly.io, and they have a secrets manager, which makes them available to the user (root, in this case) at boot time. So, the secrets are available as `$SECRET` currently.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that, maybe it has a programmatic way to get the environment variable and you can use it in your script.